# Python print statement not executing

Tags: python

I have a function that I'm calling from my main function.

```
def generate_new(tokens, outfile):
    print('NO')
    new_sents = []
    for i in range(0, len(tokens)):
        first = tokens[i]
        second = tokens[i]
    print('YES')
```

This is working fine. However, when I'm adding one more statement, only the first print gets executed.

```
def generate_new(tokens, outfile):
    print('NO')
    new_sents = []
    for i in range(0, len(tokens)):
        first = tokens[i]
        second = tokens[i+1]
        first_found = first
    print('YES')
```

I've already tried flushing the buffer. I suspect it's an indentation issue but this code was running fine previously. I added some statements to the end of the function and since then it never executes the statements outside the loop. What could be the issue? Thank you.

Comment: Didn't you get any out of bound access error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are accessing the list `tokens` out of bounds,

`range(0, len(tokens))` goes from `0` to `len(tokens)-1`

Now when you access `tokens[i+1]`, it throws an index out of bound exception and execution stops. As a result nothing after the loop gets executed.

You should be able to see the Exception on the console.

Anyway, the fix -

Either change the logic or iterate only till `len(tokens)-1`

I hope that explains the issue.

Comment: Good catch. As a sidenote, I bet if he had seen an exception he would probably have understood it went wrong, so I'm wondering whether he has a try block hiding exceptions, another common mistake beginners make.

Comment: @spectras `try except` blocks that simply `pass` in the `except` are the major reasons for bugs.

Comment: Ah yes, I was so focused on finding faults elsewhere, didn't notice this. Thanks!